# Matplotlib plot colorbar label

Tags: matplotlib, label, colorbar

I am trying to create a plot with a colorbar, with custom tick labels. When I try to create a label for a colorbar, it reverts to the original tick labels.

[image: output plot]

```
z = np.add(relzvals, shift_val)    

fig=plt.figure()
plt.contourf(x,y,z,25)
ax = plt.colorbar()
ax.set_label('cbar_label',rotation=270)
ax.set_ticklabels(labels,update_ticks=True)
```

How can I get both customizations?

UPDATE: For context, the main program require translated values, i.e.  `relzvals = z + shift_val`, and the matrix has to be translated back to `z` for plotting.

I checked the values of `z` before coming inside `plt.contourf()` but it contains the original values.

I have Python 2.7.11 and Matplotlib 1.3.1.

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.4. What version of Python and matplotlib are you using?

Comment: @DavidG Python 2.7.11, MPL 1.3.1. I updated the post above to reflect the context of my question.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give a runnable example? Either providing your data or providing some fake data which shows the same problem?

Comment: @DavidG Here is a sample data [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wrpg4lefca7q8r/G.csv?dl=0)